# Console not printing anything

Tags: java

It  is not printing anything there is no error.
kindly help me in resolving his error.
I have tried three methods to print but still not a single one is working and there isn't any error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JavaEight {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Employee> Emp = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee e1 = new Employee(101, "Ravi", "Delhi", "2000");
        Employee e2 = new Employee(102, "Vineet", "Mangalore", "5000");
        Employee e3 = new Employee(103, "Punit", "Mumbai", "3000");
        Employee e4 = new Employee(104, "Shruti", "Banglore", "6000");
        Employee e5 = new Employee(105, "Ritu", "Hyderabad", "8000");
        
        for(int i=0; i<Emp.size();i++)
        {   
            Employee e = (Employee)Emp.get(i);
            System.out.println(e);
            
        }
        Emp.forEach(i -> System.out.println(Emp));
        
        for(Employee i : Emp)
        {
            System.out.println(Emp);
        }
        
        
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have tostring method for the object??

Answer (score 1):

emp.add(e1); etc is missing

you have created the employee objects, but you did not add them to the list. thus the list is blank, and not printing anything

Comment: for(int i=0; i<Emp.size();i++)
        {   
            Employee e = (Employee)Emp.get(i);
            System.out.println(e);
            
        } now when I am printing this , it is printing something like this   com.assignment.Employee@7a81197d it is not printing values.

Comment: @user9685761 refer to method [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--)

Comment: @user9685761 if your problem is solved, you can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Itiis printing the address instead of values.

Comment: there would a tick below the vote, beside the answer. To see the values of the employee object, you have to override the toString() in the employee class.

Answer (score 0):

add Employee in your ArrayList.

```
     ArrayList<Employee> Emp = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee e1 = new Employee(101, "Ravi", "Delhi", "2000");
        Employee e2 = new Employee(102, "Vineet", "Mangalore", "5000");
        Employee e3 = new Employee(103, "Punit", "Mumbai", "3000");
        Employee e4 = new Employee(104, "Shruti", "Banglore", "6000");
        Employee e5 = new Employee(105, "Ritu", "Hyderabad", "8000");
        Emp.add(e1);
        Emp.add(e2);
        Emp.add(e3);
        Emp.add(e4);
        Emp.add(e5);
```

hope , it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your ArrayList Emp is empty.
You have created the Employee object but you have not added it to Emp.
add it to Emp like Emp.add(e1).

Comment: for(int i=0; i<Emp.size();i++) { Employee e = (Employee)Emp.get(i); System.out.println(e); } now when I am printing this , it is printing something like this com.assignment.Employee@7a81197d it is not printing values.